# openxlsx::write.xlsx throwing unused argument error for startRow

Tags: r, excel

I want to read a bunch of excel files all located in the same directory and store them in different sheets in a consolidated Excel file.

I am using a combination of `xlsx` and `openxlsx` to achieve this. The reason is, `openxlsx` can not read .xls file and `xlsx` is java based and runs out of memory throwing `GC overhead limit exceeded` error when trying to write large files.

Here is the code I am using:

```
library(openxlsx)
library(xlsx)
mnth="january"
outputFileName<-"Consolidated.xlsx"
files <- list.files(path="./Original Files", pattern=mnth, full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)

start_row<-1
lapply(files, function(x){
  print(x)
  xlFile<-read.xlsx2(x, sheetIndex = 1, startRow = 2, header =T)  #Reads all columns as factors

  #Write to Excel
  write.xlsx(xlFile, file=outputFileName, sheetName = mnth, startRow = start_row)

  start_row<- start_row + nrow(xlFile)
})
```

I am trying to read all the files with January (Ex: january2015, january 2016) and append the rows in the same sheet of a Consolidated xlsx file.

However I am getting the error:

```
 Error in write.xlsx(xlFile, file = outputFileName, sheetName = mnth,  : 
  unused argument (startRow = start_row)
```

The documentation clearly mentions that `startRow` is an optional parameter. Interestingly, `sheetName` is also an optional parameter but does not throw errors.

I have ran the code with `startRow = start_row` removed and it works as expected, i.e., the contents are repeatedly overwritten with only the contents of the last xls file prevailing.

**UPDATE**
I have changed the reading function from functions from `XLConnect` to avoid having the several functions with similar names, and I still get the same error:

```
 Error in write.xlsx(xlFile, file = outputFileName, sheetName = placename,  : 
  unused argument (startRow = start_row)
```

Here is the code with `XLConnect`:

```
lapply(files, function(x){
  print(x)
  xlFile<-readWorksheetFromFile(file = x, sheet=1, startRow=2)
  str(xlFile)
  l=list(dt,xlFile)

  #Write to Excel
  write.xlsx(xlFile, file=outputFileName, sheetName = mnth, startRow = start_row)

  start_row<- start_row + nrow(xlFile)
})
```

Comment: Not at all an R user, but you have both `xlsx` and `openxlsx` packages included here: only one of those (openxlsx) has a `startRow` argument to `write.xlsx`, so perhaps your code is called the one which doesn't have that argument?

Comment: If I explicitly mention the function to use using `openxlsx::write.xlsx(xlFile, file=outputFileName, sheetName = mnth, startRow = start_row)`, I get the error: `Error: zipping up workbook failed. Please make sure Rtools is installed or a zip application is available to R.
         Try installr::install.rtools() on Windows. `

Comment: https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/pandoc/openxlsx.html  "The openxlsx package requires a zip application to be available to R, such as the one that comes with Rtools, available here. (Windows only)"   Seems fairly clear what the issue is.

Comment: @TimWilliams : Please see update. I think it is not an issue with zip applications. In any case, I have Rtools installed and working (confirmed by typing `shell("zip")`.

Comment: I'm out of suggestions - as I noted I'm not an R user.